# React update state with interval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I just start study react and I have question
Let's say I recive data from server, and I need to add it to my front with some filter.
Data is array name|age
I want to add it to front with interval 1sec, so I need to update my state every 1sec, I try some variants and nothing is worked.
So can someone help me to understude how update state with setState every 1sec?
Here my code

```js
function App() {
    const people = [
        {name: 'David', age: 24},
        {name: 'James', age: 16},
        {name: 'Angela', age: 29},
        {name: 'Gina', age: 28},
        {name: 'Mike', age: 15},
        {name: 'Laura', age: 30},
        {name: 'Paul', age: 25}
    ]

    const [btnDisabled, setBtnDisabled] = useState(false)
    const [canDrink, setCanDrink] = useState([])

    const interval = function () {
        let i = 0;
        console.log(i)
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            console.log(i)
            if (people[i]) {
                setBtnDisabled(true)
                if(people[i].age >= 18) {
                    const arr = [...canDrink, people[i]]
                    i++
                    // @ts-ignore
                    setCanDrink(arr)
                }
            } else {
                clearInterval(interval)
                setBtnDisabled(false)
            }
        }, 500)
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <button
                disabled={btnDisabled}
                onClick={() => {
                interval()
            }}>Interval
            </button>
            <ul>{canDrink.map( elem =>
                // @ts-ignore
                <li key={elem.name}>{ elem.name }</li>
            )}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: did you try to use useEffect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `React.useEffect`. You cannot efficiently perform `setTimout`s inside Functional components.

First you would have to store a new state variable to remember the index.

```
const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(-1);
```

Then you can implement logic inside `React.useEffect` which will run when your `counter` variable updates.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    // This code will run whenever your `counter` variable updates

    // Checking if counter is a valid index
    if (counter >= 0 && people[counter]) {

        // If age of person at `counter` index is < 18, don't do anything, just update counter
        if (people[counter].age < 18) setCounter(counter + 1);

        // If it is a valid user, setTimeout to update canDrink with this user which will update UI after 1 sec
        else {
            setTimeout(() => {
                setCanDrink((canDrink) => [...canDrink, people[counter]]);
                setCounter(counter + 1);
            }, 1000);
        }
     }
}, [counter]);
```

I have made a code sandbox for you with a working example. Have a look at it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-ardinghelli-sks6z?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix 2 things. First, move `i++` out of if block. You are incrementing the counter only when condition meets. When it sees someone underage, it will never increment the counter and loop infinitely. After moving it, you will notice your `canDrink` state is changing but weirdly. That's because your interval function only knows the first version of `canDrink` array (see [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)). You can use `setCanDrink(previousState => [...previousState, people[i]])` to update your state